# File is not executable after installing with install4j

Tags: linux, install4j

I'm trying to make an installation file of some eclipse package for linux.
I specified in install4j that i want to use external launcher (the one that comes with eclipse).
After the installation i can't execute the launcher.
In the file properties->permissions i see that "allow executing file as program" is turned off.
When i turn it on everything works.
Is there any way to make it executable without interfering after installation?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a "Set the UNIX access mode of files and directories" action to the Installation screen of the installer on the Installer->Screens & Actions tab to change the permissions of the external executable.

Answer (score 0):

You can also select the file in the Distribution Tree (From the Files Tab/pane), right click it, select "edit entry" to open the dialog, go to install options and update the Unix mode to what you want.